# Use Mockito to ignore lambda when comparing Kotlin data class?

Tags: kotlin, junit, mockito

I want to assert that two instances of a `data class` are the same like this:

```kotlin
        val expectedViewState = MyViewState(
            title = "Title",
            subtitle = "Subittle",
            onTap = any()
        )

        assertEquals(expectedViewState, actualViewState)
```

These assertions always fail because of `onTap: (String) -> Unit`. Is there a way to basically ignore this field without overriding `equals` on the `data class` itself?